# Moving WhatsApp to new phone without changing number

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-transfer

Not sure if this has been asked before. I would like to move my WhatsApp installation and chats to my new phone and I would like to keep the same number associated with it, but I don't want to move the SIM with the old number into the new phone.

Everything I have read online about moving WhatsApp to new phone seems to apply only to one of two options, taking the old SIM into the new phone, or changing the number on the account to match the SIM in the new phone.

I know this is possible because I have seen French people using WhatsApp with their old French number from years back, but when I call them on their local number, that rings the phone on which the installation sits (not dual SIM)

Answer (score 0):

Bro, it's actually easy! You don't need to remove your old sim and fit into your new phone. I have added the steps for you

**First** Backup all the data and chat history to google drive from the chats section in settings in whatsapp.

> Whatsapp>>:>>Settings>>Chats>>Chat Backup

**Second** After backing up all the data install whatsapp on the new phone. Then verify your old phone number by getting the otp on your old phone and you will get a option for restoring your data from Google drive.

=>After restoring the data you will get most of the messages back on your new phone!

Yes, I have written "most of the" not "all of the". It's because not all your data gets backed-up. The data which you have downloaded on the old phone will normally gets backed-up with the chat.

To back up all the data I will recommend first downloading all the things and stuffs which you have received from others and then start backing up in your old phone!

(Or) alternatively there are many applications which can do all these things without any sort of manual uploading and downloading. You can search for them on the web and playstore (or appstore)!